# TypeScript return different type based on type arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a function `myFunc<T1, T2 = undefined>` that returns `[T1]` if `T2 extends undefined` else `[T1, T2]`.  Is it possible to make such a function without `// @ts-ignore`?

```ts
function myFunc<T1, T2 = undefined>(t1: T1, t2?: T2): T2 extends undefined ? [T1] : [T1, T2] {
    if (t2 === undefined) {
        return [t1];
    }

    return [t1, t2];
}
```

This syntax gives me a TypeScript error on each `return` statement, saying the value is not assignable to `T2 extends undefined ? [T1] : [T1, T2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional types usually cause problems in the implementation. You can't assign anything to a conditional type that still has unresolved type parameters except something of the exact same conditional type. So typescript will not let you assign `[T1]` or `[T1, T2]` to the return value.

You can use a type assertion, or you can use a separate implementation  signature, one that returns a union.  I personally prefer this second option:

```
function myFunc<T1, T2 = undefined>(t1: T1, t2?: T2): T2 extends undefined ? [T1] : [T1, T2]
function myFunc<T1, T2 = undefined>(t1: T1, t2?: T2): [T1] | [T1, T2] {
    if (t2 === undefined) {
        return [t1];
    }

    return [t1, t2];
}
```